# CI4 on live server not reflecting changes made, it shows old data. Dynamic contents and other changes are not reflected

Tags: php, session, browser-cache, codeigniter-4

I created a website using CI4 and it was working fine. On WAMP server it's working fine. Now if change anything and update the server it shows the old data and session not working properly sometime. I think browser is caching the webpage. Is there any way to disable in CI4?  Is it cache issue or session?

"Old data" means if I change a css or a section of html it wont reflect the change, and old html shows. Same for dynamic data.

Cannot login, session not holding login details. For session I am using database. Everything works fine on local server, issue only on live server. I am using plesk hosting.

Anyone have this issue?

When tried on a new pc it works fine. And if any update made and try again issue comes.

Initiated session in base controller:

```
$this->session = \Config\Services::session();
```

I use this in the controller for cache control:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
//header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
```

App configuration for session:

```
public $sessionDriver   = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\DatabaseHandler';
public $sessionCookieName  = 'ci_session';
public $sessionSavePath = 'ci_sessions';
public $sessionExpiration        = 7200;
//public $sessionSavePath          = WRITEPATH . 'session';
public $sessionMatchIP           = false;
public $sessionTimeToUpdate      = 300;
public $sessionRegenerateDestroy = false;
```

Tried Empty/Cache and hard reload.  No caching is enable in the code.

**Edit:**
I checked the browser as mentioned in comment and it is caching:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=315360000
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 9333
content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests;
content-type: text/css
date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 13:07:22 GMT
etag: "f0fc6fe8a1bdd61:0"
expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
last-modified: Wed, 18 Nov 2020 11:56:54 GMT
server: nginx
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-powered-by-plesk: PleskWin
x-sucuri-cache: HIT
x-sucuri-id: 18015
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

I don't know how this is caching.

The base controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

/**
 * Class BaseController
 *
 * BaseController provides a convenient place for loading components
 * and performing functions that are needed by all your controllers.
 * Extend this class in any new controllers:
 *     class Home extends BaseController
 *
 * For security be sure to declare any new methods as protected or private.
 *
 * @package CodeIgniter
 */

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use Config\Services; 
 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
class BaseController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
     * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
     * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $helpers = ['form', 'url','master'];
        protected $session;
    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function initController(\CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface $request, \CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface $response, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Preload any models, libraries, etc, here.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // E.g.:
         $this->session = \Config\Services::session();
         date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai');
                     $this->pager = \Config\Services::pager();
                    
                    

}
}
```

This is the login function:

```
public function login($type = 0)
    {
        $session = session();
        $model = new HomeModel();
        $model1 = new CartModel;
        if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {
            if (!$this->validate([
                'email' => [
                    'label' => 'Email',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required|is_not_unique[tbl_customers.email]',
                    'errors' => ['is_not_unique' => '{value}-Email is not registered with us']
                ],
                'current-password' => ['label' => 'Password', 'rules' => 'trim|required']
            ])) {
                $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
                $page = 'login_page';
                if (!is_file(APPPATH . '/Views/home/' . $page . '.php')) {
                    throw new \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException($page);
                }
                $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

                return view('home/login_page', $data);
            } else {
                $status = $model->checkLogin($this->request->getVar());
                if (isset($status)) {
                    $session->remove('customerData');
                    session()->set('customerData', $status);
                    $cmsrDetails = session('customerData');
                    if (!empty(cart()->contents())) {
                        $cart = cart()->contents();
                        foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {
                            $is_exist = $model1->checkItems($value['rowid'], $cmsrDetails['customerID']);
                            if (!empty($is_exist)) {
                                if ($value['qty'] != 0) {
                                    $data = [
                                        'qty' => $value['qty']
                                    ];
                                    $model1->update($is_exist['id'], $data);
                                } else {
                                    $model1->delete($is_exist['id']);
                                }
                            } else {
                                $datain = [
                                    'CMid' => $cmsrDetails['customerID'],
                                    'rowId' => $value['rowid'],
                                    'itemId' => $value['id'],
                                    'qty' => $value['qty']
                                ];
                                $model1->insert($datain);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $getCart = $model1->CartItems($cmsrDetails['customerID']);
                    if (!empty($getCart)) {
                        $model1->UpdateCart($getCart);
                    }
                    return redirect()->to('/');
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Username or Password incorrect';
                    $session->markAsFlashdata('error');
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty(session('customerData'))) {
            return redirect()->to('/');
        }
        //$data['validation'] = $this->validator;
        $page = 'login_page';
        if (!is_file(APPPATH . '/Views/home/' . $page . '.php')) {
            throw new \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException($page);
        }
        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
        echo view('home/login_page', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add some details.  `it shows the old data` - what data?  How is the data generated, and how are you updating it? `and session not working` - what does that mean? Login throwing an error? Session variables disappearing? Show us concrete, specific details. Of course the first check for session problems would be to check permissions on your `sessionSavePath` - if you are using file based sessions (you did not tell or show us that).

Comment: @Don'tPanic : 
old data means if i change a css or a section of html it wont reflect the change. and old html shows.same for dynamic data.Cannot login,session not holding login details.
for session iam using database.
Everything works fine on local server.issue only on live server. iam using plesk hosting.

Comment: Please edit your question and add that info - make it easier for others to see what they need to help you.  RE: caching - OK, so start debugging.  Using your browser's devtools, what does the network tab show? Select one of the HTML pages in question and check headers. Is it being cached? RE: sessions - OK, so start debugging. Are records being written to the DB table? Are you using the right `sessionDriver`? Did you create and configure the table? There is a lot you can check which you have not told us about ... get to work! :-)

Comment: `i think browser is caching the webpage ... if i change a css or a section of html it wont reflect the change` This is really not uncommon and a byproduct of your browser attempting to save bandwidth by caching various parts of the page. When you want the browser to for sure pull the latest code from the server, you want to "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" to ensure that happens; instructions here: https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/how-to-clear-cache-and-hard-reload-browsers/

Comment: It sounds like you have 2 separate problems (caching, and sessions). 1) Caching: the controller code you have is not correct - the `header()` code should be inside a method.  As a test, move them into one of the methods you use to actually serve a page, and check caching in your browser again. 2) Does the database table exist? When you log in, does a record get created in the table?

Comment: @Don'tPanic
**Thanks for the help :) **. As u suggested i moved header() to a controller and now it seems to work fine.
Also login working now and database get created when log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just got it working about 90% by doing as Dont Panic mentioned, added header() to controllers and added `$response->noCache();` to the base controller.

Now login and other functionality working fine.
Thanks all for helping